# Colour html table rows when matching value with another mysql table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have two Mysql tables:

Table1 columns => Name,Firstname,Age,Address

Table2 columns => Name,School,Car,Whatever

So both tables contain the same column "Name".

I need to create an html table with all data from table1 BUT when Table1 name = Table2 name I want to colour the corresponding table row in red.

can you help me to achieve that please?

I can create a html table with data from table1:

```
 echo '<table id = "mytable" border="1" cellpadding="10" width="100%" >';
                    echo '<th align="center"> Name </th>';
                    echo '<th align="center"> First Name </th>';
                    echo '<th align="center"> Age </th>';
                    echo '<th align="center"> Address </th>';

                    while($data =mysql_fetch_array($query)){

                        echo "<tr><td align='center'>". $data["Name"]." </td>";
                        echo "<td align='center'>". $data["Firstname"]." </td>";
                        echo "<td align='center'>". $data["Age"]." </td>";
                        echo "<td align='center'>". $data["Address"]." </td>"

                        echo "</tr>";

                    }
    echo '</table>';
```

I also found a sql query that returns table1 row matching with table 2 Name field:

```
select Name, Firstname, Age, Address from data.table1 INNER JOIN data.table2 ON data.table1.Name = data.table2.Name;
```

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: In query, table 1 join with table 2?

Comment: I edited my post to add what I have tried so far. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I found something else, I added a variable $style in all my "td" and I define the variable like so:

$dd = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from table2"));
$style = ($data['Name'] == $dd['Name'] ) ? 'style="background-color: red;"' : '';

But I need a loop to process each rows of table2 because right now it only highlights one matching rows in my html table.